# Find the point that is at distance $1$ from $(0,0,0)$ and at distance $3$ from $(1,2,3)$ that is closest to $(5,-2,4)$.

Tags: geometry, optimization, analytic-geometry, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have this question :

> Find the point that is at distance $1$ from $(0,0,0)$ and at distance $3$ from $(1,2,3)$ that is closest to $(5,-2,4)$.

Here is my failed attempt.

[image]

I used Lagrange multipliers and the fact that the determinant of matrix is 0 when we have non trivial solution. the quad equation went bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done great so far.  The only thing left is to substitute $x=\dfrac{57z-33}{17}$ and $y=\dfrac{42-54z}{17}$ into $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.  In other words, you have
$$\frac{2(3227z^2-4149z+1282)}{289}=0\,.$$
From this horrendous quadratic equation, you solve it using the famous quadratic formula, but not without pain, and obtain
$$z=\frac{4149\pm17\sqrt{2305}}{6454}\,.$$
That is,
$$x=\frac{3(461\pm19\sqrt{2305})}{6454}$$
and
$$y=\frac{3(461\mp9\sqrt{2305})}{3227}\,.$$
Therefore, the distances to $(5,-2,4)$ from these optimizing points are $$\sqrt{\frac{283\mp\sqrt{2305}}{7}}\,.$$
Thus, the minimizing point is
$$\begin{align}(x,y,z)&={\small\left(\frac{3(461+19\sqrt{2305})}{6454},\frac{3(461-9\sqrt{2305})}{3227},\frac{4149+17\sqrt{2305}}{6454}\right)}\\&\approx(0.638,0.027,0.769)\,,\end{align}$$
yielding the minimum distance $\sqrt{\dfrac{283-\sqrt{2305}}{7}}\approx5.794$.  On the other hand, the maximizing point is
$$\begin{align}(x,y,z)&={\small\left(\frac{3(461-19\sqrt{2305})}{6454},\frac{3(461+9\sqrt{2305})}{3227},\frac{4149-17\sqrt{2305}}{6454}\right)}\\&\approx(-0.210,0.830,0.516)\,,\end{align}$$ 
yielding the maximum distance $\sqrt{\dfrac{283+\sqrt{2305}}{7}}\approx6.877$.